# How do I have two fields for a choice?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a website in Django, and I want to have two blogs.

For each blog I need three variables: a name (that I choose from when I write my post in the admin part - do I understand correctly that this is the choice?), a title (for the view), a blog_url (for the url).

There should be a finite number of blogs, so I can select my choice from a drop-down menu when I write the post. I can do it with only one between title and url following [an example in the Django reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) - with title it would be:

```
class Post(models.Model):    
    BLOG_TITLE = (
            ("Title 1", "first"),
            ("Title 2", "second"),
        )
    blog_title = models.CharField(
            max_length=20,
            choices=BLOG_TITLE,
            blank=True)
```

I think that I need something like

```
(["Title", "url"], "blog"),
```

instead of

```
("Title", "blog"),
```

Should I define a class Blog and refer to that via ForeignKey in Post? How?

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a foreignkey relationship to new model called for example Blog.

Example:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.URLField()

class Post(models.Model):    

    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

To access the data:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1) 
post.blog.title
```

You should access the data in your template.

View Example:

```
def postview(request):
    return render('template_xyz.html', {'object': Post.objects.get(id=1) }
```

Template Example:

```
<h1>{{ object.blog.title }} </h1>
```

Comment: And then, in the `Post` class, I would have `blog_title = blog.title` and so on? (Or should I just use blog.title directly in the view?)

Comment: You will be able to access the Blog data by executing a queryset: post = Post.objects.get(id=1) 
post.blog.title

Comment: But how do I get the correspondence between the id of the blog and the choice? Do to override with `choice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`?

(I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.) (Thank you, the update is very useful!)

Comment: I think that I don't understand this question. You mean that you want to get all posts for selected blog?

Comment: Yes, eventually. The `blog.title` would be used to filter all the posts, so that I can have an index of the posts for each blog. (The `blog.url` would be needed for the url of this index.)

Comment: Post.objects.filter(blog__id=blog_id) or Blog.objects.get(id=1).post_set.all()