# Using a ForeignKey, NON NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a website in Django, and I want to have different blogs for different categories of posts. I have a model Post, which uses a ForeignKey to the Blog model.

Following the useful help I was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801553/how-do-i-have-two-fields-for-a-choice/), I have:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    # category of the blog
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # its title (for the view)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # its url (for url.py)
    url = models.URLField()

class Post(models.Model):
    # blog
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, null=True)
    # other fields
    # ...
```

Whenever I try `python manage.py migrate pad` I get

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: pad_post__new.blog_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

[...]

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: pad_post__new.blog_id
```

Do I have to set an `id` in Blog explicitly? I tried with different combinations of `blank=null` and `null=True` in different fields, but I always get this error.

Comment: First of all, you should clean previous migrations. Can you ensure that previous python manage.py schemamigration pad --auto file is removed, to regenerate it again with your null-condition's model changes?

Comment: did you run makemigrations already???

Comment: xecgr: do I remove all .py files except __init__.py and 0001_initial.py in pad/migrations ? (I don't want to break everything.)

cdvv7788: Yes, I run makemigrations. Without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of a response from OP, the advised solution in this case is to ensure you have cleaned out any lingering migrations by rebuilding/making migrations from the fresh copy of the model using the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations pad
```

In this case remember that `pad` refers to the users application name. You can leave it off of the command to make fresh migrations across the board:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Once complete you can run either the app-specific or general migration:

```
#Specific for this case
python manage.py migrate pad
#or Rebuild all available migrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If, after this, you are still having a problem then your model itself has an issue.

Comment: I think the question is, what is wrong with the models? I'm having this same problem, and none of the answers here were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, and fixed it by adding blank=True when specifying the foreignkey, as suggested [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2ricny/foreign_key_nulltrue_error/)

Hope that helps..